# Chrome extension: chrome.runtime.sendMessage and XMLHttpRequest();

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm having troubles for make a http request using `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`( in my content script ) and `chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener` ( in my backgroud html page ).

The trouble here is that http resquest not is made and i never receives callback `responseText` correctly, always comes as *undefined* in `chrome.runtime.sendMessage`.

So, i want any help for try solve this.

Here is all my code:

***Content script***

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    method: "GET",
    action: "xhttp",
    url: "http://www.example.net/echo.php?getecho",
    data: ""
}, function(responseText) {
    alert(responseText);

});
```

***Background page html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style=''>
<head>
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, callback) {
    if (request.action == "xhttp") {
        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var method = request.method ? request.method.toUpperCase() : 'GET';

        xhttp.onload = function() {
            callback(xhttp.responseText);
        };
        xhttp.onerror = function() {

            callback();
        };
        xhttp.open(method, request.url, true);
        if (method == 'POST') {
            xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        }
        xhttp.send(request.data);

        return true; 
    }
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

***PHP script***

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["getecho"]))
{       
  echo "Hello i'm php script!";
}
?>
```

***Manifest file***

```
{
   "background": {

      "page": "popup.html",
      "persistent": true
   },

"description": "Foo example",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Foo",  
   "icons": {
    "128" : "picture/wmp128.png", 
     "48" : "picture/wmp48.png" 
},

"web_accessible_resources": [

   "popup.js"
],

"content_scripts": [ 

{  

   "matches": ["<all_urls>", "*://*/*", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
   "js": ["popup.js"],
   "run_at": "document_end",
   "all_frames": true
}

],

   "permissions": [ "tabs", "background", "activeTab", "<all_urls>", "webNavigation", "webRequest", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "*://*/*" ],
   "version": "2.0"
}
```

Comment: HTML-embedded code is not allowed in chrome extensions. Use a js script file ([see the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages#manifest)) instead of background.html.

Comment: @wOxxOm, solved! thank you very much.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but it could be an sync vs. async issue. [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests) explains the difference between the two. It may be worth a shot.